# How can I add both libs and dlls to a project in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

We have a fairly large project divided into various subprojects (in visual studio this a solution with several projects). Some of the subprojects depend on an external library that supplies a set of libs to link against. The folder structure is similar to this:

```
root
    external
        thing-with-libs
           inc
           libs
              thinger.lib
    proj1
    proj2
    proj3
```

Where, say, proj1 and proj2 both link about thing-with-libs.

To accomplish this, we have root/external/thing-with-libs/CMakeLists.txt that looks similar to this:

```
project (ThingWithLibs)
set (lib_dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
add_library(ThingWithLibs STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(ThingWithLibs PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${lib_dir}/ThingWithLibs_D.lib)
```

Then, in proj1's and proj2's CMakeLists.txt, we use `target_link_libraries (ThingWithLibs)`. This adds the dependency on ThingWithLibs and everything works.

Now, in the latest drop of ThingWithLibs, there are both dlls and libs. We need to statically link against the libs and dynamically link against the dlls. The new structure of ThingWithLibs is:

```
thing-with-libs
    inc
    libs
        thinger.lib
    dlls
        thinger.dll
```

So now we need proj1 and proj2 to both statically link against thinger.lib, but we also need thinger.dll to be copied to our bin directory at some point during the build. I believe I can solve this with a post-build step to copy the dll, but I have only been able to get that to work as a post-build step in proj1 and proj2, not as a post-build step for ThingWithLibs. It seems better to have ThingWithLibs know everything there is to know about using ThingWithLibs, so I'd rather have that CMakeLists.txt file deal with the copy.

Perhaps related, perhaps unrelated, there is no visual studio project for ThingWithLibs--cmake doesn't create one. My current guess is that the reason we don't get the post-build step of copying to work when in ThingWithLibs' CMakeLists.txt is because, with no visual studio project, there isn't anything to perform the post-build step.

Have other people solved this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just for clarification: `ThingWithLibs` now link some other dll? Or you want `ThingWithLibs` to be dll?

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I should have been more clear and I have updated the question to (hopefully) add more clarity. To answer your question, we need to both statically link against ThingWithLibs.lib and dynamically link with the newly-dropped ThingWithLibs.dll.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the areas where CMake could really use some improvement.

Currently, there seems to be no other way than to copy dlls manually in a post-build step.

There are several ways to do this: If the dll is being built by a separate project, it's I find it most convenient to use CMake's install mechanism or obtain the location of the DLL from the imported target when using packages.

If the dll is built from the same package, you can either [adjust the output directory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), so that the dll file is already built to the same directory as the exe that needs it. If that is not an option, you can go with a separate copy step. This can happen [as a custom command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) that is attached either as a post-build step to the target that builds the dll, or as a pre-build step to the target that needs the dll, or [to a custom target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) that does just the copying and which in turn all of [the targets that need the dll depend on](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html).

The full path to the dll can be obtained from the [`$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions).

Finding the right approach that works for you can be a bit fiddly. It depends on what your build setup looks like and in which cases you want the dll copy operation to run. So I'd suggest you setup a small test project and spend an afternoon exploring the different options. It's really not as hard as it looks once you get the hang of it, but you should take your time and explore the different options thoroughly.

Comment: Great answer, I tend to prefer the install option of CMake too. Perhaps you should add that sometimes extending the %PATH% environment variable can be sufficient.

Comment: @Andre Right. Some IDEs also allow setting directories from which DLLs are loaded when launching an executable from within the IDE (for example, Visual Studio's Binary Directories in the Directories property sheet). Unfortunately, neither of those options is configurable through CMake.